# uploadify 3 Select file not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flash, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I created a page with an uploader. As uploader I use Uploadify 3. The code is working on all browsers except for IE9. When I turn IE 9 in compat mode it is working. In IE9, I can't push the upload button. It shows, but there is no reaction to the click. So no file select dialog is opened. In Opera, chrome and FF the button works and when I click the file open dialog is showed.

Flash is running in IE9. (version 11,0,1,152) (youtube is working)

When I rightclick the button I don't get flash info. When I do this in all other browsers I get flash info. When I rightclick in youtube (in ie9) I also get flash info....?

This is my uploadify jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#fileInput').uploadify({ 
        'swf': '/Content/Scripts/uploadify3/uploadify.swf', 
        'uploader': '/nl-nl/Attachment/Upload', 
        'cancelImage': '/Content/Scripts/uploadify3/uploadify-cancel.png', 
        'checkExisting': '/nl-nl/Attachment/Check', 
        'multi': true, 
        'buttonText': 'Upload', 
        'postData' :{'RelationId' : '@cookie'}, 
        'sizeLimit': 2147483647, 
        'auto': true, 

        onError: function(a, b, c, d) { 
            if (d.status == 404) 
                alert("Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: " + "<?= getcwd() ?>"); 
            else if (d.type === "HTTP") 
                alert("error " + d.type + ": " + d.status); 
            else if (d.type === "File Size") 
                alert(c.name + " " + d.type + " Limit: " + Math.round(d.sizeLimit / 1024) + "KB"); 
            else 
                alert("error " + d.type + ": " + d.text); 
        }, 
        onUploadComplete: function() { 
            $("#Grid").data('tGrid').ajaxRequest(); 

        } 
    }); 
});
```

Did I made a mistake? Is this a flash bug? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know the real problem, but for someone else with this problem. It works after deploy, just not in debugger mode.

Comment: Yes I too had the same problem removed flash and reinstalled with the previous version and everything is fine.

Comment: I think it is the new flash, I'm about to downgrade flash in IE to test.

Comment: If it is the new flash they have a "dont run local only in IE 9" policy enabled or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

It works when you replace download swf with whole path

```
http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.swf
```

It's not elegant solution, but it works.
I have this issue only in localhost.

Now selecting button works perfect in IE, but we've got Security Error.
To solve it you need to add crossdomain.xml file in your root directory.

Example crossdomain.xml for all domains (just for test)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

or try to add line in  Global.asax file
Add this line in RegisterRoutes method

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("crossdomain.xml");
```

Comment: Just had exactly the same problem. I replaced my swf path with the live path and it worked straight away..

Comment: THANK YOU! I'd been debugging this for yonks! For me, I had to change the path and add crossdomain.xml (routes line didn't work).